# how to to request the Task to stop working?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using such code:

```
private Task[] tasks;
private volatile bool stayConnected;

....

tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (stayConnected) {
        ...
    }
}

....

public void Disconnect()
{
    stayConnected = false;
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

My code doesn't work - tasks never ends. I guess they do not receive fresh `stayConnected = false` value by some reason, probably just declaring field as `volatile` is not enough.

What is the correct way to signal a task to stop working?
I don't want to "kill" the task, instead i want to "request" the task to finish.

I've found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx%5C) that suggests to use CancellationToken, should I use it or probably you can suggest something better? Can I use one CancellationToken for several tasks?

Also it's interesting why my initial code doesn't work.

Comment: Why you use `volatile`?

Comment: because it doesn't work without `volatile`. with `volatile` it doesn't work too.

Comment: Yes. Create a CancellationTokenSource pass the token it creates into the task factory method, then signal cancel on the cts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use [CancellationToken Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) but Boolean value.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;
private Task[] tasks;

void Start()
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tasks = new Task[1];
    tasks [0] = Task.Run(() => SomeWork(cts.Token), cts.Token);
}

void SomeWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // some work
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}

void Cancel()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: should i call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`? why not just replace `while (true)` to `while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)`

Comment: Is is posssible, but the best practice is to use exception to identify whether task was completed or canceled and handle this situations differently. In case of infinite loop there is no need in exception.